# Insert and Fetch Data from Microsoft Azure Using Android.Getting Error

Tags: java, android, azure

I am working with **Microsoft Azure Cloud Database**, inserting data from Android Application.

i referred below mentioned link code,for **insert and fetch data from azure** using my android App. its Works fine.

**Problem:**

I have **added two more columns in Azure database**. I am not able to interact that columns using demo code.its little complicated for me.

Please help me,how to add few more columns in android code,**Insert and Fetching data from cloud Database**.

**[Link i referred](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-data/)**

ToDoActivity.java

```
public class ToDoActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Mobile Service Client reference
     */
    private MobileServiceClient mClient;

    /**
     * Mobile Service Table used to access data
     */
    private MobileServiceTable<ToDoItem> mToDoTable;

    //Offline Sync
    /**
     * Mobile Service Table used to access and Sync data
     */
    //private MobileServiceSyncTable<ToDoItem> mToDoTable;

    /**
     * Adapter to sync the items list with the view
     */
    private ToDoItemAdapter mAdapter;

    /**
     * EditText containing the "New To Do" text
     */
    private EditText mTextNewToDo;

    /**
     * Progress spinner to use for table operations
     */
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    /**
     * Initializes the activity
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingProgressBar);

        // Initialize the progress bar
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

        try {
            // Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided

            // Mobile Service URL and key
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "https://newapk.azure-mobile.net/",
                    "****************************",
                    this).withFilter(new ProgressFilter());

            // Get the Mobile Service Table instance to use

            mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class);

            // Offline Sync
            //mToDoTable = mClient.getSyncTable("ToDoItem", ToDoItem.class);

            //Init local storage
            initLocalStore().get();

            mTextNewToDo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textNewToDo);

            // Create an adapter to bind the items with the view
            mAdapter = new ToDoItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row_list_to_do);
            ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewToDo);
            listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            // Load the items from the Mobile Service
            refreshItemsFromTable();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            createAndShowDialog(new Exception("There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL"), "Error");
        } catch (Exception e){
            createAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the activity menu
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Select an option from the menu
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_refresh) {
            refreshItemsFromTable();
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Mark an item as completed
     *
     * @param item
     *            The item to mark
     */
    public void checkItem(final ToDoItem item) {
        if (mClient == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Set the item as completed and update it in the table
        item.setComplete(true);

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {

                    checkItemInTable(item);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (item.isComplete()) {
                                mAdapter.remove(item);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");
                }

                return null;
            }
        };

        runAsyncTask(task);

    }

    /**
     * Mark an item as completed in the Mobile Service Table
     *
     * @param item
     *            The item to mark
     */
    public void checkItemInTable(ToDoItem item) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        mToDoTable.update(item).get();
    }

    /**
     * Add a new item
     *
     * @param view
     *            The view that originated the call
     */
    public void addItem(View view) {
        if (mClient == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create a new item
        final ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem();

        item.setText(mTextNewToDo.getText().toString());
        item.setComplete(false);

        // Insert the new item
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    final ToDoItem entity = addItemInTable(item);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(!entity.isComplete()){
                                mAdapter.add(entity);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        runAsyncTask(task);

        mTextNewToDo.setText("");
    }

    /**
     * Add an item to the Mobile Service Table
     *
     * @param item
     *            The item to Add
     */
    public ToDoItem addItemInTable(ToDoItem item) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ToDoItem entity = mToDoTable.insert(item).get();
        return entity;
    }

    /**
     * Refresh the list with the items in the Table
     */
    private void refreshItemsFromTable() {

        // Get the items that weren't marked as completed and add them in the
        // adapter

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {
                    final List<ToDoItem> results = refreshItemsFromMobileServiceTable();

                    //Offline Sync
                    //final List<ToDoItem> results = refreshItemsFromMobileServiceTableSyncTable();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mAdapter.clear();

                            for (ToDoItem item : results) {
                                mAdapter.add(item);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (final Exception e){
                    createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");
                }

                return null;
            }
        };

        runAsyncTask(task);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh the list with the items in the Mobile Service Table
     */

    private List<ToDoItem> refreshItemsFromMobileServiceTable() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return mToDoTable.where().field("complete").
                eq(val(false)).execute().get();
    }

    //Offline Sync
    /**
     * Refresh the list with the items in the Mobile Service Sync Table
     */
    /*private List<ToDoItem> refreshItemsFromMobileServiceTableSyncTable() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        //sync the data
        sync().get();
        Query query = QueryOperations.field("complete").
                eq(val(false));
        return mToDoTable.read(query).get();
    }*/

    /**
     * Initialize local storage
     * @return
     * @throws MobileServiceLocalStoreException
     * @throws ExecutionException
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> initLocalStore() throws MobileServiceLocalStoreException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {

                    MobileServiceSyncContext syncContext = mClient.getSyncContext();

                    if (syncContext.isInitialized())
                        return null;

                    SQLiteLocalStore localStore = new SQLiteLocalStore(mClient.getContext(), "OfflineStore", null, 1);

                    Map<String, ColumnDataType> tableDefinition = new HashMap<String, ColumnDataType>();
                    tableDefinition.put("id", ColumnDataType.String);
                    tableDefinition.put("text", ColumnDataType.String);
                    tableDefinition.put("complete", ColumnDataType.Boolean);

                    localStore.defineTable("ToDoItem", tableDefinition);

                    SimpleSyncHandler handler = new SimpleSyncHandler();

                    syncContext.initialize(localStore, handler).get();

                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");
                }

                return null;
            }
        };

        return runAsyncTask(task);
    }

    //Offline Sync
    /**
     * Sync the current context and the Mobile Service Sync Table
     * @return
     */
    /*
    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> sync() {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    MobileServiceSyncContext syncContext = mClient.getSyncContext();
                    syncContext.push().get();
                    mToDoTable.pull(null).get();
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        return runAsyncTask(task);
    }
    */

    /**
     * Creates a dialog and shows it
     *
     * @param exception
     *            The exception to show in the dialog
     * @param title
     *            The dialog title
     */
    private void createAndShowDialogFromTask(final Exception exception, String title) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error");
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Creates a dialog and shows it
     *
     * @param exception
     *            The exception to show in the dialog
     * @param title
     *            The dialog title
     */
    private void createAndShowDialog(Exception exception, String title) {
        Throwable ex = exception;
        if(exception.getCause() != null){
            ex = exception.getCause();
        }
        createAndShowDialog(ex.getMessage(), title);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a dialog and shows it
     *
     * @param message
     *            The dialog message
     * @param title
     *            The dialog title
     */
    private void createAndShowDialog(final String message, final String title) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.create().show();
    }

    /**
     * Run an ASync task on the corresponding executor
     * @param task
     * @return
     */
    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> runAsyncTask(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            return task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            return task.execute();
        }
    }

    private class ProgressFilter implements ServiceFilter {

        @Override
        public ListenableFuture<ServiceFilterResponse> handleRequest(ServiceFilterRequest request, NextServiceFilterCallback nextServiceFilterCallback) {

            final SettableFuture<ServiceFilterResponse> resultFuture = SettableFuture.create();


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mProgressBar != null) mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            ListenableFuture<ServiceFilterResponse> future = nextServiceFilterCallback.onNext(request);

            Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<ServiceFilterResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                    resultFuture.setException(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (mProgressBar != null) mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                        }
                    });

                    resultFuture.set(response);
                }
            });

            return resultFuture;
        }
    }
}
```

ToDoItemAdapter.java

```
public class ToDoItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem> {

    /**
     * Adapter context
     */
    Context mContext;

    /**
     * Adapter View layout
     */
    int mLayoutResourceId;

    public ToDoItemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId);

        mContext = context;
        mLayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the view for a specific item on the list
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        final ToDoItem currentItem = getItem(position);

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        row.setTag(currentItem);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkToDoItem);
        checkBox.setText(currentItem.getText());
        checkBox.setChecked(false);
        checkBox.setEnabled(true);

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    checkBox.setEnabled(false);
                    if (mContext instanceof ToDoActivity) {
                        ToDoActivity activity = (ToDoActivity) mContext;
                        activity.checkItem(currentItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return row;
    }

}
```

ToDoItem.java

```
public class ToDoItem {

    /**
     * Item text
     */
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("text")
    private String mText;

    /**
     * Item Id
     */
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
    private String mId;

    /**
     * Indicates if the item is completed
     */
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("complete")
    private boolean mComplete;

    /**
     * ToDoItem constructor
     */
    public ToDoItem() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getText();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes a new ToDoItem
     *
     * @param text
     *            The item text
     * @param id
     *            The item id
     */
    public ToDoItem(String text, String id) {
        this.setText(text);
        this.setId(id);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the item text
     */
    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the item text
     *
     * @param text
     *            text to set
     */
    public final void setText(String text) {
        mText = text;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the item id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the item id
     *
     * @param id
     *            id to set
     */
    public final void setId(String id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    /**
     * Indicates if the item is marked as completed
     */
    public boolean isComplete() {
        return mComplete;
    }

    /**
     * Marks the item as completed or incompleted
     */
    public void setComplete(boolean complete) {
        mComplete = complete;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof ToDoItem && ((ToDoItem) o).mId == mId;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-offline-data/ for offline storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a documents https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/ that clearly explained how to use the android clinet library to interact with Azure Database for various operations.

I think you can refer to these sample in the document to write own code to implement your needs.

Any other concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: How to fetch specific column data from Azure database.

Comment: can you able to add code snippet for fetching data.

Comment: @Kumar You can refer to the offical sample at Github https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/GettingStartedWithData

Comment: Thanks for your Valuable Reply Friend :)

Comment: can you tell One thing After Sync to Azure database Server from local. its ,Erasing From Local or Not. then ,How can i came to know each row inserted in database Server from Local.

Comment: @Kumar The offline sync keeps the consistent data between server and local to avoid conflict, not simply erase. You can refer to the section `offline testing` of the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data/ to make sure the function validity.

Comment: My Application is  Every 2 mins data is inserting in local, then every 5 mins data is Sync to Azure. Each Row Data After Inserting in AZURE server, i want to delete from Local Database. My Question is how can i know My each row is Inserted or not in Server. Any response will  send back to client End from Server. Else Other Solution?

Comment: @Kumar Could you please create a new thread to discuss this issue since your new question is not directly related to the original issue, it would be better if you open up a new thread for the new question. In this way, our discussion here will not deviate too much from the original issue. This will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 1):

You have to make changes in your **ToDoItem.java**
It is the class which corresponds to the table in database.

whenever you make changes to the table in azure. 
In ur case, when u are adding new columns to table in azure, say **newcol1** and **newcol2**, You have to add

`@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("newcol1")
private boolean newColumnOne;`

to your ToDoItem.java file. Only then u could have access to new columns in  ToDoActivity.java

Comment: Thanks for your reply,How can i access (insert) data in that new columns from ToDoActivity.class

Comment: there must be an object of TodoItem.java called "item", just add ''item.setNewcol1()'' (using setter method). and then send your insert query. It will work fine

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void addItem(View view) {
    if (mClient == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Create a new item
    final ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem();

    item.setText(mTextNewToDo.getText().toString());
    item.setComplete(false);
    item.setNewColumnOne("dataabc");
    item.setNewColumnTwo("dataxyz");


    // Insert the new item
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final ToDoItem entity = addItemInTable(item);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!entity.isComplete()) {
                            mAdapter.add(entity);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error 3rd");
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    runAsyncTask(task);

    mTextNewToDo.setText("");
}
```

just add data through setNewColumnOne(); as i did.
rest of the code should be same.

P.S. dont forget to create getter setter and constructor for TodoItem.Java

Comment: Thank you very much ,i am trying with this code.if i am getting any error i let you know.

Comment: also one more thing, How to fetch specific column data from Azure database.